# imap_setflag_full seems to do nothing?

Tags: php, email, imap, flags

I'm trying to flag a message as seen:

```
var_dump(imap_setflag_full($mail, "9", "\\Seen", ST_UID));
```

The output is `bool(true)` but when I then re-fetch my messages (`imap_fetch_overview`) this is what I see:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (15) {
  ["subject"]=>
  string(3) "..."
  ["from"]=>
  string(47) "... <...@...>"
  ["to"]=>
  string(14) "...@..."
  ["date"]=>
  string(30) "Wed, 8 Dec 2021 12:04:59 +0200"
  ["message_id"]=>
  string(68) "<...>"
  ["size"]=>
  int(2580)
  ["uid"]=>
  int(9)
  ["msgno"]=>
  int(9)
  ["recent"]=>
  int(1)
  ["flagged"]=>
  int(0)
  ["answered"]=>
  int(0)
  ["deleted"]=>
  int(0)
  ["seen"]=>
  int(0)
  ["draft"]=>
  int(0)
  ["udate"]=>
  int(1638957899)
}
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I can't spot what.

Comment: How did you open your folder?  Did you use read-only?

Comment: @Max using `imap_open($server, $user, $pass);`, I believe it should not be read-only without any flags supplied, unless it's read-only by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in [the comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-setflag-full.php#99500) of `imap_setflag_full`, `pop3` apparently does not support flags other than the deleted one. After switching to `IMAP` flags work as expected.